# Multiple searchbar implementation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two searchbar in my view controller...
As expected if I touch the first search bar it will go to the first segue..
And if I touch the second search bar it will go to the second segue..
This code works fine, however if I run this with other iphone devices with bigger or smaller screen..
This will not work because I've only used the frame of searchbar as the identifier..

I have search a lot if there other ways to identify which searchbar was been clicked but I have not found any implementation like this..
Is there anyway to identify searchbar when I used the function `searchBarShouldBeginEditing`..

Thanks!

```
    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
    NSLog(@"searchBarShouldBeginEditing");
    NSLog(@" Description is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(searchBar.frame));


    if (([NSStringFromCGRect(searchBar.frame) isEqualToString:@"{{108, 27}, {267, 56}}"]) || ([NSStringFromCGRect(searchBar.frame) isEqualToString:@"{{108, 33}, {559, 56}}"]))
    {
        NSLog(@"to");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSearchSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else if(([NSStringFromCGRect(searchBar.frame) isEqualToString:@"{{108, -3.5}, {267, 56}}"]) || ([NSStringFromCGRect(searchBar.frame) isEqualToString:@"{{108, -3.5}, {559, 56}}"]))
    {
        NSLog(@"from");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromSearchSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"searchSuggest" sender:self];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set two outlets for each `UISearchBars` as like below.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var firstSearchBar:UISearchbar!
 @IBOutlet weak var secondSearchBar:UISearchbar!
```

Check which one is clicked in delegate method. Use below code snippet

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{


if (searchBar == firstSearchBar){
 // perform actions for first bar
   NSLog(@"to");
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSearchSegue" sender:self];
}

if (searchBar == secondSearchBar){
// perform actions for second search bar
   NSLog(@"from");
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromSearchSegue" sender:self];
}



return YES;
```